# multiple divs with a single .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

After hours ploughing through all the posts on this I'm still without a solution. I've got at least 6 divs in a single HTML file which I need to load to a master HTML file. The contents of each `div` are posted to different `div` containers in the master file. I can get this to work with the code below, but I'm carrying out 6 separate loads of the same file which is clearly resource and time-wasting.  I've tried separating ID's with commas on a single line, but I get strange results where data gets posted to the wrong containers. Does anyone know how to achieve a single load?

```
$(function() {
    $("#CountryList").load("https://URL #CountryStore");
    $("#YearList").load("https://URL #YearStore");
    $("#ProductList").load("https://URL #ProductStore");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make only one request using `$.get()` and parse the response yourself and place the various parts where you want them

```
$.get('https://URL', function(data){
   var $data= $(data);
   $( "#CountryList" ).html($data.find('#CountryStore'));
   $("#YearList").html($data.find("#YearStore"));
   $("#ProductList").html($data.find("#ProductStore"));

});
```

This is essentially what `load()` is doing internally